# Vue get children of a component passed in a parent component

Tags: vue.js

How do I get access the children that were passed into the children component in the parent component?
I understand the explanation may be confusing, what I want is this, similar to React "children" prop.

```
<div class="layout">
    <item-component v-for="i in 10" :key="i">{{ i }}</item-component>
</div>
```

And in the `item-component` I want to access the `i` variable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use [Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html).

In item-component you need to put in:

```
<slot></slot>
```

exactly where you want the value of **i** to be.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `i` in scripts, just add property in `item-component`, for example named `no` and put it in for:

```html
<div class="layout">
    <item-component v-for="i in 10" :key="i" :no="i" ></item-component>
</div>
```